# Breakpoint not hitting JS file

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

Hi all i have this bit of code in an external js file that has been added to the page and im using MVC and JSTree in .NET.

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$("#divJsTreeDemo").jstree({
    // List of active plugins
    // I usually configure the plugin that handles the data first
    // This example uses JSON as it is most common
    "json_data": {
        // This tree is ajax enabled - as this is most common, and maybe a bit more complex
        // All the options are almost the same as jQuery's AJAX (read the docs)
        "ajax": {
            // the URL to fetch the data
            "url": "/WebTree/GetTreeNodes",
            // the `data` function is executed in the instance's scope
            // the parameter is the node being loaded 
            // (may be -1, 0, or undefined when loading the root nodes)
            "data": function (n) {
                // the result is fed to the AJAX request `data` option
                return {
                    "operation": "get_children",
                    "id": n.attr ? n.attr("id").replace("node_", "") : 1
                };
            }
        }
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

try putting the key word debugger; where you want to break it like

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    debugger;
    //rest of your code

});
```